# webViewDidStartLoad not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

`webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are not working.

What I have already done:

1. `webView.delegate = self;`
2. added `UIWebViewDelegate`
3. placed the code in `viewDidAppear`.

Here is the code:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
            print("Webview started Loading")
        }

        func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
            print("Webview did finish load")
        }
```

Comment: show your complete code with request made. It will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you didn't keep the reference to your `webView` in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for Swift 3

```
        let url = "http://apple.com"

    let requestURL = URL(string:url)
    let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("Webview started Loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Check this simple example code which is working fine:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = "http://apple.com"

        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        print("Webview started Loading")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        print("Webview did finish load")
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)